# Why is coset multiplication given by $a\mathcal{N}\cdot b\mathcal{N}=a\cdot b\mathcal{N}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $\mathcal{N}$ is a normal subgroup of group $\mathcal{G}$, quotient group is given by
$$\mathcal{G}/\mathcal{N}=\{a\mathcal{N}: a\in\mathcal{G}\}$$
and the group product is given by
$$a\mathcal{N}*b\mathcal{N}=a\cdot b \mathcal{N},a,b\in\mathcal{G}$$
where $*$ represents the operation of the coset group and $\cdot$ represents the operation of $\mathcal{G}$. In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jhVMBXl5jTA&list=PLi01XoE8jYoi3SgnnGorR_XOW3IcK-TP6&index=22&ab_channel=Socratica) video
they say that the product of two cosets is obtained by taking the product every element in the first coset with every element in the second coset. When i try to show the equivalence between the two, I calculate as follows,
$$a\mathcal{N}\cdot b\mathcal{N}=a\mathcal{N}a^{-1}\cdot a\cdot b\mathcal{N}=\mathcal{N} a\cdot b\mathcal{N}$$
Is this correct, and if so, why should
$$\mathcal{N} a\cdot b\mathcal{N}= a\cdot b\mathcal{N}$$
if not, how can i show the equivalence.

Comment: Hint. Look at the definition of "normal subgroup".

Comment: all I can see is $a\mathcal{N}a^{-1}=\mathcal{N}$ which  I used here $a\mathcal{N}\cdot b\mathcal{N}=a\mathcal{N}a^{-1}\cdot a\cdot b\mathcal{N}=\mathcal{N} a\cdot b\mathcal{N}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a\mathcal N \cdot b\mathcal N= a (bb^{-1})\mathcal N b\mathcal N=(ab)b^{-1}\mathcal N b\mathcal N=(ab)\mathcal N\mathcal N=ab\mathcal N$$

While it is true that $a\mathcal N\cdot b\mathcal N=ab\mathcal N$ holds as a product of sets, it's better to understand this by showing $a\mathcal N* b\mathcal N:=(ab)\mathcal N$ is well-defined, i.e. if $a\mathcal N=a'\mathcal N, b\mathcal N=b'\mathcal N$, then $ab\mathcal N=a'b'\mathcal N$, which can be generalized to e.g. the product of quotient rings where $(a+I)(b+I)=abI$ isn't always true as sets.

Comment: I see now, although I'm not sure I understand the significance of the second point you made

Comment: Some experiences with semigroup or ring theory or universal algebra might help.

Comment: cool, I'll get reading. Thanks for your help